# Hacer dinamico un archivo con pandas

Tags: python, poo, pandas

Tengo dos archivos csv(uno se llama paises.csv y el otro provincias.csv) La idea es que paises.csv almacena una lista de paises y ademas indica que provincias tiene. provincias.csv almacena toda una lista de provincias con algunas caracteristicas adicionales. Ahora bien, paises.csv lo que hace es almacenar por nombre algunas de las provincias que estan en provincias.csv y asignarlas a un pais

Este es el paises.csv

```
Numero,Nombre,provincias
Pais1,argentina,ar1|ar2|ar3|ar4|ar5
Pais2,chile,ch1|ch2
Pais3,brasil,br1|br2
```

Y este es el provincias.csv

```
Numero,Nombre,contagiosTotales,contagiosDiarios,contagiosActivos,muertesTotales,muertesDiarias,vacunasAplicadas,vacunasSinAplicar,vacunasTotales
ar1,ciudad autonoma de buenos aires,687000,2845,178000,9302,36,1011854,1608,1013462
ar2,santa fe,2,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
ar3,c,4900,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
ar4,d,9340,92,12,12,12,12,12,12
ch1,e,300,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
ch2,f,234,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
ar5,g,234,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
br1,h,300,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
br2,i,234,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
```

Lo que quiero es que me devuelva el pais con mas contagios totales. Esto quiere decir que para saber los contagios totales de un pais hay que sumar los contagios totales de todas las provincias que corresponden a ese pais. Y, a su vez, comparar entre si todos los paises para ver cual es el que tiene el maximo de contagios totales y devolverlo en pantalla.

Comment: dado que el archivo piases contiene las provincias, lee las provincias de cada pais y luego realizas la suma en base a sus provincias. Otra es que no muestras que has intentado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como no sé si esto se trata de un ejercicio que te hayan pedido, y ya que no muestras lo que has intentado, no te voy a dar la solución completa, pero te voy a mostrar cómo poder agregar una columna "Pais" a tu tabla de datos, que simplificará mucho la tarea posterior al permitirte hacer cosas como `datos.groupby("Pais").sum()` para calcular sumas agregadas por paises, etc.

La idea es la siguiente. Del primer csv podemos leer la lista de países así:

```
import pandas as pd
paises = pd.read_csv("paises.csv")
```

y éste sería el contenido de esa tabla:

```
  Numero     Nombre           provincias
0  Pais1  argentina  ar1|ar2|ar3|ar4|ar5
1  Pais2      chile              ch1|ch2
2  Pais3     brasil              br1|br2
```

Mi idea es crear un diccionario inverso a partir de los datos de esta tabla. En ese diccionario las claves serían las provincias ("ar1", "ar2", etc.) y los valores serían el nombre del país. Eso hará después muy eficiente buscar a qué país corresponde una provincia dada.

Ese diccionario (al que llamaré `indice`) lo creamos por ejemplo así, iterando por las filas de esa tabla:

```
indice = {}
for i, fila in paises.iterrows():
  pais = fila.Nombre
  provincias = fila.provincias.split("|")
  for provincia in provincias:
    indice[provincia] = pais
```

Con los datos de ejemplo el diccionario `indice` resultante es:

```
{'ar1': 'argentina', 'ar2': 'argentina', 'ar3': 'argentina', 
 'ar4': 'argentina', 'ar5': 'argentina', 'ch1': 'chile', 
 'ch2': 'chile', 'br1': 'brasil', 'br2': 'brasil'}
```

Ahora leemos la tabla de datos en sí:

```
datos = pd.read_csv("provincias.csv")
```

Y añadiremos una nueva columna a esta tabla, con el nombre del país al que corresponde cada fila. Este nombre lo sacamos del diccionario `indice` antes construido, usando como claves los valores de la columna "Numero":

```
datos["Pais"] = datos.Numero.apply(lambda x: indice[x])
```

Ejemplo de la tabla resultante (he quitado columnas para ceñirnos a lo que interesa):

```
  Numero                           Nombre  contagiosTotales       Pais
0    ar1  ciudad autonoma de buenos aires            687000  argentina
1    ar2                         santa fe                 2  argentina
2    ar3                                c              4900  argentina
3    ar4                                d              9340  argentina
4    ch1                                e               300      chile
5    ch2                                f               234      chile
6    ar5                                g               234  argentina
7    br1                                h               300     brasil
8    br2                                i               234     brasil
```

Creo que a partir de aquí ya es sencillo agrupar por paises, encontrar máximos, etc. Inténtalo y si no lo consigues edita tu pregunta para mostrar qué has intentado y qué te ha fallado.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, no me daba tiempo para responder :)

Comment: @abulafia gracias por la ayuda, te hice unas preguntas en la respuesta que acabo de agregar. No quise editarla por si a otra persona le puede servir la pregunta